# How to calculate iterative and recursive solutions?

Tags: c

Following needs to be calculated  (iterative und recursive Solution)

Sum = 1 – 1/2 + 1/3 – 1/4 + - . . . 1/n (n > 0) with float reihe (int n)

We have the following so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 float reihe(int n)
 {
     float sum = 0;
     if (n = 1)
         sum = 1;

     else
     {
         for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
         {
             sum += (1 / i) - (1 / (1 + i));
         }
     }
         return sum;
 }


 int main(void)
 {
     float z;
     z = reihe(5);
     printf("%d", z);
     return 0;
 }
```

Would appreciate any of your help. Have a good day.

Comment: The step for `i` in your for loop is obviously wrong. Try to write up which values are summed up in, lets say, 4 iterations

Comment: `(1 / i) - (1 / (1 + i))` will be `1` with `i == 1`, **and zero for all other values of `i`.**

Comment: Ignoring the problem with integer division, your series will look like this: `1-1/2+1/2-1/3+1/3-1/4` which is 1-1/(n+1). You should rethink how to increment the counter `i`.

Comment: Ok I understand the Problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this? Not tested, but it compiles and runs... 
BTW/ take a close look at the use of `1.0`.  If you use `1` it is interpreted as an integer and not a float and you division is always rounded to 1 or 0 and you lose all decimal values...

```
float reihe(int n)
{
    float sum = 0;
    float base = 1.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if ( i % 2 ) { 
            sum += base/i;
        }
        else {
            sum -= base/i;
        }
    }
        return sum;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works now, thanks. Tried to change the values to 1.0.

Comment: I'm of two minds; yes, we may be doing someone's homework, but I'm not a teacher and don't really care.  I'm of the mind that examples are the best way of learning and it also keeps me sharp as I haven't touched C in a couple years.

Comment: @Ctx The problem is fairly clear and the OP has made some effort and posted a MCVE. So there is no need for such comments; there's nothing wrong with answering this question - it is not a code-begging question.

Comment: @pedwards Keep in mind that you should avoid `double` literals like `1.0` when working with `float`. Most of the time the compiler will optimize them away, but in some cases you can get inaccuracy bugs or slower code. It is better to consistently use `float`, that is: `1.0f`.

Comment: @Lundin Please don't try to tell me what I may comment or not. Answers like this are neither helpful to the OP nor to others. The point in doing homework is to learn solving problems and the comments to the questions helped the OP to solve the issues with the code himself. What good does this answer?

Comment: @Ctx There's nothing indicating that this is homework. And it doesn't matter. As per site policy we don't care _why_ someone is asking, as long as they have put sufficient effort into the question. [Help - on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." This page dictates what's on-topic here, not you, not me.

Comment: @Lundin I don't dispute that the question is on-topic, we are talking about the _answer_. You get the difference, don't you? And since you are already citing it: Where is the "description of the difficulty you are having solving it."?

Comment: @Ctx What exactly is wrong with it? It answers the question and it is on-topic.

Comment: @Lundin I think I have made my opinion clear enough, the question "What exactly is wrong with it" in my eyes is more than answered in the previous comments. Why do you try so hard to inflict your opinion on me?

Comment: re: double literals... I agree and updated the code.  Thanks for the feedback gents but time and experience has taught me to wait 24 hrs before responding to rhetoric like this as it has never added value to anyone's life... ever!